# Gallery OnFling event not working

Tags: android, gallery, onfling

I've come up with a problem using a Gallery of Views, by Views I mean that is not a gallery of simple ImageViews, but instead a complex structure that could be resumed as follows:

- Gallery

  1. FrameLayout

     a. LinearLayout

     - ImageView (*)

  b. LinearLayout (-)

  - TextView
  - LinearLayout

    1. ScrollView

       a. LinearLayout

       ```
       - ImageView
       - TextView
       ```

The problem is that the onFling is not getting called whenever I fling over the ImageView (*). Don't know if the problem might come in the fact that I have a ScrollView over there, nevertheless the LinearLayout (-) has visibility GONE.

Do you know what might me causing the problem, and if you do, what could be a solution for it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is imageView is 'clickable' or 'focusable'?

Comment: is clickable indeed, any problems with that? since clicking is not the same as flinging

Comment: Actually thanks to Lukas for giving me enough information to know the issue. The problem arise whenever I try to implement some of the events of the children's contained within the view that is being displayed by the Gallery. 

So basically, for my interests, I've moved my ImageView clicking event logic, to the Gallery setOnItemClickListener, in that way I'm achieving what I wanted.